# Where to find Mathematica 10.0.1 Updates and Bug Fixes for Student Edition?

Tags: version-10

Over the last week I've been dealing with some extremely frustrating bugs--bad enough that it's interfering with my ability to complete assignments for an already difficult enough class. I won't go into the specific bugs, as they've been discussed here largely already.

From what I can see,there is an update from v10.0, but I've been unable to find anything to tell me how/where to get it. Is this a limitation of the student edition?

Updates: I also logged on to my user portal. It doesn't appear in the downloads downloads section. No one is responding on the live chat, so I submitted the email.

On the surface, I can see why this might have been marked a duplicate, but that post was the trial version, and none of the responses got me any closer to a fix. I hope I'm not breaching etiquette by updating my post. I really just want to stop chasing down the patch so I can get back to my homework and exams.

Comment: I guess this is a question for WRI support. Posting on community.wolfram.com might just be useful, too.

Comment: I have v10 student edition and received an email on 27 Sept directing me to update to 10.0.1 (OSX). Which all worked fine. I'm not sure if there is a list of bug fixes for this release somewhere.

Comment: You should be able to download it from the [Wolfram User Portal](https://user.wolfram.com/portal/login.html) after logging in.

Comment: Thanks, Karsten 7. That's exactly what I was looking for.